# Oracle: Cannot connect from entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I've an oracle server, already installed on a remote server.

I've installed oracle latest provider, to use them in visual studio with entity framework.

But when I'm trying to connect to the server, I got this exception:

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.

I'm really new to the oracle world, and I cannot find what is the problem or even how to debug it.

I saw that listeners are ups, by doing a `lsnrctl status` I've my listener on the port 1521.

But, I saw that i've the security like this: "`Security ON: Local OS Authentication`", but since I've no common users between the server and the client, can it make somes troubles?

Should I have some specials rights on my user? In local, I can connect myself with the sqldeveloper tools.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Some more informations:
The server runs under windows, it has the OracleXETNSListener service started. I forgot to mention, but the server firewall is off.

**Edit 2**

I tried to download the oracle sql developer on my workstation, and I connected myself with exactly the same informations.(I just saw that in fact sql developer use a "base" connection instead of "TNS", which seems to be used by the EF?

Comment: Could you post your complete connection string (or connection parameters details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended by using the devart connector: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

it worked for me directly in all mode(Direct or normal). If only I did tried it this morning, I will have loosed less time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your tns names via AD or locally on your machine? If it's local then you'll need to make sure that you have the correct connection descriptors listed in the tns names file located in the default location - this depends on Oracle version.

There are known issues around entity framework and connecting to remote instances, but these can be overcome with a l

Comment: With a ? So, I've an "Host=MyServer" in the `lsnrctl status`, and I use this same MyServer to connect. I can ping the machine with this name(and it respond with the correct IP).

Comment: Is your Oracle install listening on the default port? Also, what happens if you use "tnsping [servername]"?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Oracle Provider, your connection string should look something like this:

> Data Source=*{serverAddress}*/xe;User Id=*{UserName}*;Password=*{Password}*;

Example:

> Data Source=localhost/xe;User Id=scott;Password=tiger

I suggest you to always mention the Oracle Instance Identifier (which in the Express Edition is always **xe**), so you don't have to rely on your tns config settings.

Comment: But it's when I'm specifying the data source in the tool of VS2010 that my problem is happening